# When Is My Business Code Actually Being Executed?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I got a Spring Boot app. It's running as such:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyBooty implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyBooty.class, args);
    }

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(...);
        someClass.doStuff();
System.out.println("Why Am I appearing Before \"Started In\" log line?");
    }
```

Does what I need. But I noticed this line in the output: `Started MyBooty in 17.594 seconds (JVM running for 18.206)`, which was printed after some of my console output.

This made me think my code was actually executing before the app was actually initialized. So I did some research found [this blog post](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/11/13/run-code-at-spring-boot-startup/) and then set up a new class as such:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationStartup implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>{

    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(...);
        SomeClass.doStuff();
        return;
    }

}
```

Which supposedly executes after after application startup. Well, I still see the `Started app in...` output **after** my output again.

So, concept check. Are things working as intended and I'm just being naive? Or is there maybe something missing? If someone could knowledge share on the topic that would be appreciated.

Again, my code runs and does **exactly** what I need it to, but I just want to make sure I'm using/taking advantage of Spring Boot properly.

In case it's unclear what I'm asking, I'm asking **Why does the "Started App in X seconds" message appear after my output?** I ask this because I simply found it confusing that it said the app was started after my business code had **ALREADY** ran. This question is a conceptual question about how spring boot starts up.

Edit: Console Output

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.2.RELEASE)

2016-09-23 17:44:56.598  INFO 1004 --- [           main] o.b.p.MyBooty              : Starting MyBooty on ********* with PID **** (C:\...\MyBooty)
:
:
:
2016-09-23 17:44:59.152  INFO 1004 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-09-23 17:44:59.154  INFO 1004 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
2016-09-23 17:44:59.725  INFO 1004 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-09-23 17:44:59.725  INFO 1004 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3074 ms
2016-09-23 17:45:00.228  INFO 1004 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-09-23 17:45:00.234  INFO 1004 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-23 17:45:00.234  INFO 1004 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-23 17:45:00.234  INFO 1004 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-23 17:45:00.234  INFO 1004 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-23 17:45:00.824  INFO 1004 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@453da22c: startup date [Fri Sep 23 17:44:56 CDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-23 17:45:00.901  INFO 1004 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-09-23 17:45:00.902  INFO 1004 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-09-23 17:45:00.925  INFO 1004 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-09-23 17:45:00.925  INFO 1004 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-09-23 17:45:00.962  INFO 1004 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-09-23 17:45:01.136  INFO 1004 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-09-23 17:45:01.215  INFO 1004 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
Why Am I appearing Before "Started In" log line?
2016-09-23 17:45:17.063  INFO 1004 --- [           main] o.b.p.MyBooty              : Started MyBooty in 20.814 seconds (JVM running for 23.279)  <----- Why is this after my output?
2016-09-23 17:45:22.675  INFO 1004 --- [)-10.168.50.106] inMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin : Application shutdown requested.
2016-09-23 17:45:22.676  INFO 1004 --- [)-10.168.50.106] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@453da22c: startup date [Fri Sep 23 17:44:56 CDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-23 17:45:22.678  INFO 1004 --- [)-10.168.50.106] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Comment: I don't understand. Please post an example with the _console output_ you're talking about. Spring initializes itself inside the `SpringApplication.run(..)` call.

Comment: What were you expecting and what is your question? Are you asking if there is a bug somewhere in the console output? If so, why do you think so? Or are you looking for documentation on `ApplicationListener`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Added Output

Comment: Where does the _Why Am I appearing Before "Started In" log line?_ come from...? Post a [mcve].

Comment: @Tunaki I suppose, intuitively I would expect to see the `Started App in X seconds` before my output. Not after. I'm just curious as to why this is.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ....It's literally an sout in the run method, I'll add it too

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Added.

Comment: @DovahkiinvasNormandy That's just how `SpringApplication.run` is writing the log events. [Check the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.2.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#322) the log line you're talking about is printed just after the listeners are called. It doesn't change anything: that `ApplicationStartup` component you have will be invoked when the application has been configured successfully and ready to go. I guess, you could argue that it should log that line _before_ invoking the listeners, meh.

Comment: @Tunaki That was the bit information I was after. This just simply confused me that I see "App started" log message after my business logic had already executed. I just wanted to make sure my code was where it should be. Feel free to make that an answer if you want

Comment: See the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner) for `CommandLineRunner` as well.

Comment: Because the run method is called at the end of the initialization process!

Comment: @DovahkiinvasNormandy The code in the `ApplicationStartup` listener is not part of the business logic, nor should it be. Take a look at the link @Sotirios gave, if you want to do introduce business logic, implement `ApplicationRunner` or `CommandLineRunner`. Those will be invoked _after_ the application boots (and after that specific log line you're concerned about).

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks, I think I got it cleared up now. I just was unaware of what was happening was all and wanted to be sure I was setting my application up in the conventional way. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You class is annotated with [`@SpringBootApplication`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html), which makes it automatically register as a Spring Bean.

The [`SpringApplication`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html) [`run(Object source, String... args)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String...-) method you are calling ends up calling [`run(String... args)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run-java.lang.String...-).

The `run()` method calls the [`afterRefresh()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#afterRefresh-org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext-org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments-) method *right before* it logs the "Started ..." message, and `afterRefresh()` will call the `run()` method of any registered [`ApplicationRunner`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html) and [`CommandLineRunner`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html) beans.

Or, as the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-command-line-runner) says it:

> If you need to run some specific code once the `SpringApplication` has started, you can implement the `ApplicationRunner` or `CommandLineRunner` interfaces. Both interfaces work in the same way and offer a single `run` method **which will be called just before `SpringApplication.run(…​)` completes**.